# How does first empty string initialized in java?

Tags: java

Below is [default constructor](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/49a11875e369/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l238) of `java.lang.String`:

```
public String() {
    this.value = "".value;
    this.coder = "".coder;
}
```

My question is where is `"".value` come from? Is object `""` created with default constructor?

Comment: please provide valid reference and check line 139 (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

Comment: Here's a valid link to the source, you might want to include it in your answer: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/49a11875e369/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l238

Comment: I would guess it comes from the `String` pool, and is managed by native code; note that `""` is the simplest possible `String` (and the JVM is initialized with multiple values in the `String` pool). There is a note at the top saying *All string literals in Java programs, such as {@code "abc"}, are implemented as instances of this class.* And `""` is a `String` literal.